Get Big-O of algorithm that depends on input value
I've passed an algorithmic section recently in a certain company and an interviewer asked me to code this task:

There is is a string 3[abc]2[dk]m. You need to write a code that transforms it to abcabcabcdkdkm (a number is a repetition qualifier of a substring).

I wrote the code succesfully, but got stuck on a question, what asymptotic complexity it has, because running time of the algorithm depends on input values, not on input length.
Is there a method to estimate such algorithms?

Is your algorithm independent from the qualifiers themselves, the number of qualifiers, and the length of the substrings?

We'd have to see your solution to evaluate its runtime complexity. Or at least a detailed explanation of your solution.

You need to write exponentially many characters, so the algorithm cannot run faster than that.
E.g. if the input string 999...9[a] has n characters, you need to write N=999...9 many characters. Since N is encoded with $\log_{10} N$ characters, the output string is approximately $10^{n-3}$ long.
Hence, your algorithm is $\Omega(10^n)$.
You can do more fine-grained analysis, such as arguing that the algorithm runs in time $O(n \cdot 10^k)$ where $k$ is the longest consecutive sequence of digits in the string. Then you can argue that if the longest consecutive string is constant or even logarithmic in the input length, the algorithm runs in polynomial time.

clear explanation, thanks a lot! I've not expected that running length decoding can have complexity close to popular NP-problems.

Thats because tiny problems can have enormous outputs. Given n,  print 10^n:  even with a problem size of just 10 (decimal digits), n is up to 10 billion - 1, and 10^n is a ten billion digit number.
